# Simple recursion function to save values to List

Tags: java, xml, recursion

This question relates to recursion. Consider the program shown below (not my real code, but this explains the problem I have).

The function **must** use recursion as shown, and what I want to do is have a way that each leaf value instead of getting printed out, is saved to a list. So finally I get a `List<String>` that when I print out gives me the contents of each leaf node.

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
"<title text=\"title1\">\n" +
"    <comment id=\"comment1\">\n" +
"        <data> abcd </data>\n" +
"        <data> efgh </data>\n" +
"    </comment>\n" +
"    <comment id=\"comment2\">\n" +
"        <data> ijkl </data>\n" +
"        <data> mnop </data>\n" +
"        <data> qrst </data>\n" +
"    </comment>\n" +
"</title>\n";

DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

List<String> results = traverse(doc.getFirstChild());

//Want to print out results list here...

public static List<String> traverse(Node node){
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
    for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
        traverse(node.getChildNodes().item(i));         
    }
    return null;
}
```

So my question is, how can I re-write the traverse function in a way that, it still uses recursion but saves all leaf nodes to the list. And then it returns the list of all values.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Does "must use recursion" imply this is homework? (This wouldn't be a problem, but I would retag the question accordingly)

Comment: Did you even try anything? There is not even much to do! Don't expect this site to give you code withouth trying first...

Comment: I want to re-write the traverse function, in a way that it still uses recursion, but saves all leaf nodes to the list, and then returns the list of all values.

Comment: I have tried a lot, and this is not homework. See some of my previous questions, I need to use recursion for to be able to properly transform an xml document into a table.

Comment: So where is the problem, you need a list. Hint: you can pass it around as a parameter or use the OO way and define an instance attribute... btw: I wonder why you use recursion at all, the given exmaple can be properly parsed without any recursion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one stores in a List the same Strings you print with your traverse function and you don't need to pass the List as an argument:

```
public static List<String> traverse( Node node ) {
        List<String> results = new LinkedList();
        results.add(node.getNodeName());
        if ( node.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0 ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++ )
                results.addAll(traverse(node.getChildNodes().item(i)));
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this was the solution I was looking for. Actually it was similar to what I had, but I noticed I had another bug. Apparently, if the List is of some other object type, you need to add a `new` object to the list, not the recurring one!

Comment: I thought you said you wanted the contents of the list to contain each leaf node. This gives you a list with all nodes.

Comment: @Kevin that’s true... but the main thing I was after was a way to store the recursive data in a list. I guess the real solution is a mix between yours and this one, but I side with this since I like the way it does not modify the function signature, whereas yours does.

Comment: You can filter the Strings you add to the list by simply adding an IF before "results.add(node.getNodeName());" so that you can check if the node is a #text node and then add it's child value; this way the function still works and you can have leaf nodes only.

Comment: @Larry: It's not the problem you think it is. See my updated answer. I think it's a bit sloppy to allocate a new linked list for every node in the xml tree as in this solution.

Comment: Yes of course, but since he didn't want to change the signature... Of course (as someone told somwhere here) designing a class with traverse( Node node ) as a method could result in a better solution!
Your solution looks good too, but i'd prefer the one involving the class...

Answer (score 0):

You could either return a list and add the elements from the recursive calls to the result list of the current call or pass the list as a parameter and add the result directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
public static void traverse(Node node, List<String> results) {
    if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() == 0) {
        // leaf node
        results.add(node.getNodeValue());
    }
    else {
        // walk all children
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            traverse(node.getChildNodes().item(i));
        }
    }
}
public static List<String> traverse(Node node) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
    traverse(node,result);
    return result;
}
```